# How to set password for pdf files?

Tags: linux-mint, password, encryption, pdf

I need to password protect my PDF file(s), because I am going to send them through email and I want anyone who would view my PDF file(s) to be prompted for a password.

How can I add a password to a PDF in Linux Mint 17.1?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the program `pdftk` to set both the owner and/or user password

```
pdftk input.pdf output output.pdf owner_pw xyz user_pw abc
```

where `owner_pw` and `user_pw` are the commands to add the passwords `xyz` and `abc` respectively (you can also specify one or the other but the `user_pw` is necessary in order to prohibit opening).

You might also want to ensure that  encryption strength is 128 bits by adding (though [currently 128 bits is default](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-output-enc-strength)):

```
.... encrypt_128bit
```

If you cannot run `pdftk` as it is no longer in every distro, you can try `qpdf`. Using `qpdf --help` gives information on the syntax. Using the same "values" as for `pdftk`:

```
qpdf --encrypt abc xyz 256 -- input.pdf output.pdf
```

Comment: Default is 128 bit encryption (at least in `pdftk 2.02-2`).

Comment: Could be useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028522/how-can-i-install-pdftk-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic  (Docker is the easy way.)

Answer (score 43):

pdftk depends on old libraries, and so is no longer in the repos of Fedora / CentOS. As a replacement, I prefer qpdf

```bsh
qpdf --encrypt [readpass] [ownerpass] 256 -- [infile].pdf [outfile].pdf
```

Comment: I used Docker to overcome. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028522/how-can-i-install-pdftk-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic

Comment: It seems that Evince (document reader) version 3.18.2 can only open PDFs which I encrypted with 128 instead of 256.

Comment: @gloschtla I used 256 and evince worked as expected. I'm still on Bionic, though (Ubuntu 18.04). Hopefully evince didn't go backward in newer versions.

Comment: FWIW: on Evince-3.36.7, unlocking the 256-bit version seems to work.

Answer (score 16):

The pdftk toolkit allows for this type of functionality on Linux.

- open your Ubuntu Terminal `CTRL+ALT+T`
- install pdftk by using this command: `sudo apt-get install pdftk`
- make sure pdftk is now installed by writing this on the terminal: `pdftk`. You will see a bunch of pdftk command instructions if it already installed
- simply use this command to add a password to your existing pdf document: `pdftk <source>.pdf output <destination>.pdf userpw <password>`

Example:

```
pdftk Mydocs.pdf output Mydocs_pass.pdf userpw secretword
```

http://wildabdat.tumblr.com/post/13245065154/how-to-add-password-to-your-pdf-docs-on-ubuntu

Comment: Note: For idiots like me, you have to actually type "output"

Answer (score 7):

You can also export an encrypted PDF file from Libre Office (File -> Export as PDF -> Security tab -> Set Passwords -> Set open password), if necessary importing your existing PDF into the Draw program first.

Comment: opening the non-encrypted PDF in LibreOffice Writer didn't work for me.

Comment: What about LibreOffice Draw, @gloschtla?

Answer (score 5):

Using tools from the Poppler Toolset (from a package like `libpoppler` or `poppler-tools`), you can achieve this with a combination of `pdftops` and `ps2pdf`.

```
pdftops in.pdf out.ps
ps2pdf -sUserPassword=XXXXX -sOwnerPassword=YYYYY out.ps out.pdf
```

Note that to set a User (view) password, you must set an Owner (edit) password.

Answer (score 2):

On Fedora, you can use **pdf-stapler** to set a password for a PDF file, and also perform other pdftk-like operations.

Example to set the *user* password (the one required for **opening** the file):

```
pdf-stapler -u QRNFFtVXA-8PqF cat input_file.pdf output_file.pdf
```

This is the password you think of most likely about setting a password to a PDF file.

In case you want to set the *owner* password (the one that defines **permissions** like printing, commenting, ect.), use the `-o` option.