# How do I password-protect PDF file so that it may be opened in Windows with only Adobe installed?

Tags: windows, password, pdf

I am running Ubuntu Linux and would like to password-protect some pdf files such that the recipient, running Windows, can open them with nothing more than Adobe, if they know the password.  Can this be done?

This question was closed on the moderators because they thought it was already answered by [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187404/how-to-set-password-for-pdf-files) I can't agree unless someone can answer this question affirmatively:

Are common Windows tools like Adobe able to open pdf files with passwords embedded by tools like pdftk or qpdf?  In other words, are pdf file passwords defined by a standard that all such tools, including Adobe follow?  Are the passwords generated by one program compatible with the password reading capabilities of another program?

If the answer is yes, then indeed my question is redundant.  But I looked for an answer to this question without finding one.

So I am asking that this question be reopened on this basis.

Comment: `with nothing more than Adobe` is not the same as `with only Adobe`

Comment: Sorry, but I believe that you’re being pedantic. If `pdftk` produced an output file that could be read only by the XYZZY file reader application, Anthon’s answer to the linked question wouldn’t have been accepted and wouldn’t have gotten 50 votes.  Note that there is some discussion in the comments of which (non-Adobe) file readers can and cannot read `pdftk`’s output; if *Adobe* couldn’t read it, that would have been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `pdftk`

example

```
pdftk <source>.pdf output <destination>.pdf userpw <password>
```

or let adobe do that for you https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/password-protect-pdf.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/460603)

Comment: @MC68020 fixed, thanks

Comment: well, if I had adobe installed in Ubuntu, it would be easier.  I came upon another method that I think works: A pdf may be opened in Open Office Writer and then exported to a pdf with password protection.  If it doesn't work I will hear from my recipient tomorrow.

Comment: @SteveCohen that link does not require you to install adobe pdf, it's just drag and drop